# How to compare two AST built from C++/C code?

Tags: c++, c, tree, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I can get AST from C++/C code (libclang for Python) and parse it and I can get some tokens from it, but I want to compare two AST. Do you know some algorithms which will help me to compare two trees and get info about how this trees is same (in persent or other metrics).

Comment: Since you tagged C++, try using [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)